# In chat, "enable desktop notification" is sometimes hidden underneath the footer

Tags: bug, chat, design

In chat the "Enable desktop notification" link sometimes get under the footer:

[image: what is under it?]

Comment: [Yeaaaah....](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=432246#432246).

Comment: This is still the case and, in fact, chat doesn't look any different all these years later.